# Showing invertibility of an $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem:**

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^P = 0$ for some integers $p>0$, show that $I-A$ is invertible and that $(I-A)^{-1} = I + A + \cdots + A^{P-1}$

**My attempt** has sadly come up short. Given my very limited linear algebra experience, I have a hard time seeing the connection between the givens, and the desired result.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to show $(I - A)(I + A + \cdots + A^{p-1}) = I$:

\begin{align}(I - A)(I + A + \cdots + A^{p-1}) &= (I  - A)I + (I - A)A + \cdots + (I - A)A^{p-1}\\
& = I - A + A - A^2 + \cdots + A^{p-1} - A^p\\
& = I - A^p = I.
\end{align}